# Apache UIMA Annotation required to trace Address

Tags: uima

We have a requirement where we need to track the  “Address“ data in the unstructured document using Apache UIMA. 
Address can be from any geography.
Some of the sample Address of UK geography are as below..
190 Stanley road Llanddoged Conwy LL26 6CM
227,Sankey street,Bourne,Lincolnshire,PE10 1LW

It would be helpful if you can share the possible annotation for identifying the Address Data from an unstructured document.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the [RUTA workbench](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.workbench) to write rules to extract addresses. It will **really** speed up and ease your work with UIMA.

Comment: Can you please share any example how to do it using RUTA workbench

Comment: The Workbench is the development/tooling support for the UIMA Ruta language. A good start is to think about why you are recognizing the examples as addresses, and then model these properties in rules that automate your decisions. This leads normally to the usage of dictionaries for known streets or cities, keywords like "street", and regular expressions of these features combined with numbers, words (of different capitalization), and other properties like whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches (examples refer to UIMA-specific tools):

- manually specify extraction rules, e.g., with [UIMA Ruta](http://uima.apache.org/ruta.html), [zanzibar](https://code.google.com/p/zanzibar/), [UIMA Regex](https://sites.google.com/site/uimaregex/), ...
- annotate enough examples and train a model, e.g, with [ClearTK](https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/), [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/), ...

What approach is best for you depends on your requirements. Many people think that statistical models are superior to rule-based approaches in general. However, it's sometimes faster to write some rules than to annotate enough examples.

(I am a developer of UIMA Ruta)